# image alignment vs image stabilization?

Tags: image, opencv

From my understanding, image alignment and image stabilization are two different things. I consider that image alignment is just about shifting (rotating or translating) the image so that it follows a specific axis, but without modifying the original image. On the other hand, image stabilization tries to modify the original image so that most of it looks similar to the previous ones. Am I correct in this reasoning?

Considering this, for a radar-based image, in which it is going to be applied some mechanical stabilization, is it worth using an image stabilization technique? Or just using the output of the mechanical stabilization with some kind of image alignment??

Radar image example:
[image: Radar image]

Cheers

Comment: Can you give an example of a radar-based image you would be working with?

Comment: @Jello editted post with picture ;)